# Why can't I change Apple ID email?

Tags: icloud, email, apple-id

The [Apple ID account servicing page](https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage) makes provision for changing the email address associated with an account. Not just the "contactable at" address, but changing the primary address, using the option "Change Apple ID".

I want to do this for my five-year-old son's Apple ID - change it from the existing hisname@icloud.com to a Google Account hisname@gmail.com.

I have already added hisname@gmail.com against "Contactable At".

When I begin to change the primary address, I see the following pop-up, as expected (since I am the parent of the account-holder)...

[image]

The only problem is, that consent notice is never sent. Rather, the input form just updates to display the following error in red, including the bold HTML tags...

[image]

```
<b>Could not send request to Robert.</b><br/>Your Apple ID change request could not be sent at this time.
```

As a test, I have attempted to change the Apple ID address to test@mydomain.com (I can use any wildcard prefix at my domain). That time, the consent verification WAS successfully sent.

So, why won't Apple accept hisname@gmail.com?

Comment: Is the address already in use as a contactable or recovery address? If so, that may be preventing it.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer. You can't switch to an address already used as a Contactable At address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From comments (& this took me years to figure out initially;)

You can't change an Apple ID address to one that is already in use as a 'Contactable at' or 'Recovery' address.

Once removed from there, then it will allow you.